# how to display measuring unit with google chart api

Tags: google-visualization

i want to display the values on the y-axis with $ but i couldn't figure out how it is done. is it even possible? if yes please how can i do it? is it also possible to make use a gradient in bars ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a format string in [`chxs`](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#axis_label_styles). Use `cUSD` to format as US dollars.

Here's an example from the docs:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart
    ?cht=s
    &chd=s:984sttvuvkQIBLKNCAIi,DEJPgq0uov17zwopQODS,AFLPTXaflptx159gsDrn
    &chxt=x,y,r
    &chxr=0,0,1000000,250000|1,0,60|2,0,5000
    &chxs=0N*e*,000000|1N*cUSD*Mil,FF0000|2N*sz2*,0000FF
    &chs=250x125
```

The relevant portion being `chxs=...1N*cUSD*Mil,FF0000`.

Comment: @Yassir It's all documented very well in the link I provided. I strongly advise you learn how to read documentation. You can use a format string such as `$s`.

Comment: yup i found it at Axis Label Styles.